# What is the correct data type for address offsets in C?

Tags: c, types

I have to work with a lot of `memcpy()`s and dynamically allocated memory. To facilitate this job I use a variable `offset` to copy and modify data according to my needs. For now, `offset` is a `unsigned long` variable, that works fine. I know that, in the end, there would be no difference in using `unsigned long` other than, say, `size_t` but nevertheless I'm wandering whether there exists a more appropriate data type for such a variable

Comment: Or perhaps `off_t` if you're on a POSIX system? Though it's officially for "file sizes" and is signed (to allow for both positive and negative offsets).

Answer (score 3):

The type you are looking for is `ptrdiff_t`, defined in [C11 7.19.2](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.19).

> The header `<stddef.h>` defines [...] `ptrdiff_t` which is the signed integer type of the result of subtracting two pointers [...]

Answer (score 0):

An offset is the difference between two memory addresses/pointers. Therefore, the most obvious choice is [`ptrdiff_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/ptrdiff_t).

On the other hand, the main difference between `ptrdiff_t` and [`size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t) is that the former is signed, whereas the latter is unsigned. Due to sacrificing one bit for the sign, it is possible that `ptrdiff_t` may be unable to represent very large differences in addresses, which results in undefined behavior.

Therefore, if the offsets are guaranteed to always be positive, it may be more appropriate to use `size_t` to represent offsets. The macro [`offsetof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/offsetof) does this, too. It expands to a value of type `size_t`, not `ptrdiff_t`.

Comment: `offsetof` returns always a non-negative value. So it can use an unsigned result. In contrast to `offsetof`, the pointer difference, you can get a negative result, what is something like 0xFFFFFFxxx if stored in an unsigned type. that's at least ugly.

Comment: @harper: I agree that `size_t` should not be used for negative offsets. That is why I used the formulation `"if the offsets are guaranteed to always be positive"` in my answer. Since the OP states that they are currently using `unsigned long` for storing offsets, I assume that they are guaranteed to always be positive (or at least non-negative).